# when using fontAwesome 5 in react-native : "0.64.2" it shows crossed out box

Tags: react-native

when using fontAwesome 5 in react-native : `0.64.2` it shows crossed out box

```
import React from 'react'
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import FontAwesome5 from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';

function TodoItem({ item, pressHandler }) {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => pressHandler(item.key)}>
            <View style={styles.text}>
               
                <FontAwesome5 name={'comments-dollar'} size={50} color="red"/>
                <Text style={styles.text}>{item.text}</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    text: {
        padding: 16,
        marginTop: 16,
        borderColor: '#bbb',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderStyle: 'dashed',
        borderRadius: 10

    }
})

export default TodoItem
```

Comment: Could you further explain what you mean with "shows crossed out box"?

Comment: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/24224603/36590346-5d205a62-18b4-11e8-9fb9-5b3258f493cd.png , it shows me this red crossed image

Comment: Try rebuilding your project